# mysql: concat is not accepting year as first expression in select if()

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am using xampp with mariadb (10.1.28). In my yii2 project I wrote a query:

```
$offer  = Offer::find()
                ->select('`offer`.*, If( ( Concat(Year(`offer`.`date`),"-'.$utc_date.'")>`offer`.`date` ) ,(CONCAT(Year(`offer`.`date`),"-'.$utc_date.'")) , (Concat(Year(`offer`.`date`)+1,"-'.$utc_date.'")) ) AS `start_date`')->all();
```

when the result of the if() is false, the query performs as expected. but if it is true an error is thrown

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `start_date`

when I start the concat with the "-'.$utc_date.'" it works but I don't want this output.

Comment: How does your final query looks like?

Comment: The yii is probably messing up your expression. Try using `select(['start_date' => new \yii\db\Expression('...your expression...')])`

Comment: replace `createCommand()->rawSQL` with the `->all()` or `->on()` in the end of your query and paste the output